# Create apparel highlights with photoshop

Tags: photoshop, lighting, highlights, retouching, clothing

I have been doing some photoshoot using 2 lightboxes directly on the item. The result is decent, but the items has a very unnatural lighting, which I would like to fix on Photoshop with some effect.

Here is what I shot:
[image]

And here is what I am looking for:

[image]

Any suggestion to achieve those highlights in post editing?

Thanks!

Comment: What is different in the amazon photo from yours that you want to achieve? Yours looks fine to me.

Comment: Those highlights that look like natural light...

Answer (score 1):

A simple method is to shoot from exactly the same position with different lighting conditions so that the shadows appear at different positions. Then you align the images (even though you are shooting from the same fixed position, a shift of a few pixels can easily occur), and transform to linear colorspace. A linear combination of these pictures then corresponds to how the picture would have looked if you had taken it under the corresponding linear combination of the different lighting conditions.  You must make sure the white balance is fixed, you should not use auto-white balance.

This allows you to compile a picture of the object illuminated by many lights, shining from different direction so that it is almost uniformly illuminated. When you are done, you transform the result back to sRGB colorspace and then you can correct the white balance.

Comment: Thanks, but the idea was not to repeat the photoshoot. If I was to repeat, I would change my lighting so it can create better highlights. The question is if there is a way to fake this on Photoshop

Answer (score 0):

In comparing your desired result to your sample, I don't think lighting or highlights are the big difference. The main two differences are:

- the other sample is simply brighter. Increase your exposure, either in shooting or post-processing
- perhaps *more* importantly, the wrinkles / folds in the sample you link on Amazon look more natural and orderly. Yours looks, well, *rumpled*. Paying a lot more attention to the setup will save you work later — and perhaps let you get results you just can't otherwise.